# Why BSS segment is "16" by default?

Tags: c, linux, size, storage-class-specifier

As per my knowledge, segmentation for c program is:

```
        High address
|---------------------------|
|env/cmd line args vars     |
|---------------------------|
|      stack segment        |--> uninitialized auto vars
|---------------------------|
|---------------------------|
|---------------------------|
|      heap segment         |--> dynamic allocated memory
|---------------------------|
|      BSS segment          |--> uninitialized static/global vars
|---------------------------|
|      data segment         |--> initialized static/global vars
|---------------------------|
|      text segment         |--> initialized auto vars/exec instructions
|---------------------------|
        Low address
```

On my RHEL 5.4 64-bit machine, for below c program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
}
```

when I do:

```
# size a.out
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1259     540      16    1815     717 a.out
```

I am unable to understand why is

> bss=16

As I am not declaring/initializing any global/static vars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worse on Windows with gcc:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    return 0;
}
```

compile:

```
C:\>gcc main.c
```

size:

```
C:\>size a.exe
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   6936    1580    1004    9520    2530 a.exe
```

bss includes the whole linked executable and in this case various libraries are linked in which do use static c initialisation.

Using [-nostartfiles](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) gets a much better result on windows. You can also try with -nostdlib and -nodefaultlibs

compile:

```
C:\>gcc -nostartfiles main.c
```

size:

```
C:\>size a.exe
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    488     156      32     676     2a4 a.exe
```

Remove all the libraries (including the c library) and you get an "executable" with exactly what you've compiled and a bss size of 0:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int _main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    return 0;
}
```

compile:

```
C:\>gcc -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs main.c
```

size:

```
C:\>size a.exe
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     28      20       0      48      30 a.exe
```

The executable won't run however!

Comment: You mean to say c libs have global/static vars declared within them right?

Comment: Not necessarily the c library, but various support libraries to get a working executable for your OS. Here, on Windows there's a lot of crud around main() to make it a working app. It's worth looking a the `objdump -S ./a.out` output on your system to see how much code surrounds what should be a simple piece of code. Your understanding is correct, it's just that the compiler adds support libraries "silently"

Comment: @DragonX it's also worth doing `gcc -v main.c` and checking the final linker step to see what libraries get linked against on your system. Under windows, for me, it's `-lmingw32 -lgcc_eh -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_eh -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/.../crtend.o` Quite a few, although most are DLLs