# Why has the .bss segment not increased when variables are added?

Tags: c, linux, elf, memory-layout, data-segment

Recently,I learned that the `.bss` segment stores uninitialized data. However, when I try a small program as below and use `size(1)` command in terminal, the `.bss` segment didn't change, even if I add some global variables. Do I misunderstand something?

```
jameschu@aspire-e5-573g:~$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
    {
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
jameschu@aspire-e5-573g:~$ gcc -c test.c 
jameschu@aspire-e5-573g:~$ size test.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     89       0       0      89      59 test.o
jameschu@aspire-e5-573g:~$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int a1;
int a2;
int a3;

int main(void)
{
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
jameschu@aspire-e5-573g:~$ gcc -c test.c 
jameschu@aspire-e5-573g:~$ size test.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     89       0       0      89      59 test.o
```

Comment: try adding `int big[1024]` or so. The bss may have a base size that doesn't change with only three variables.

Comment: possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217181/size-command-in-unix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SIZE command in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217181/size-command-in-unix)

Comment: The command shows the size it does not modify the size. I appreciate that is not what you meant, but that is what you wrote.  Semantics is important in natural language as well as code.  I changed the title so the question is semantically correct and about the BSS and the compiler and not about the size command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the way global variables work.

The problem that is being solved is that it is possible to declare a global variable, *without initializing it*, in several `.c` files and not getting a duplicate symbol error. That is, every global uninitialized declaration works like a *weak* declaration, that can be considered `external` if no other declaration contains an initialization.

How it this implemented by the compiler? Easy:

- when compiling, instead of adding that variable in the `bss` segment it will be added to the `COMMON` segment.
- when linking, however, it will merge all the `COMMON` variables with the same name and discard anyone that is already in other section. The remaining ones will be moved to the `bss` of the executable.

And that is why you don't see your variables in the `bss` of the object file, but you do in the executable file.

You can check the contents of the object sections using a more modern alternative to `size`, such as  `objdump -x`. And note how the variables are placed in `*COM*`.

It is worth noting that if you declare your global variable as `static` you are saying that the variable belongs to that compilation unit, so the `COMMON` is not used and you get the behavior you expect:

```
int a;
int b;
static int c;

$ size test.o
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
 91       0       4      95      5f test.o
```

Initializing to `0` will get a similar result.

```
int a;
int b;
int c = 0;

$ size test.o
text      data    bss    dec     hex    filename
 91       0       4      95      5f test.o
```

However initializing to anything other than `0` will move that variable to `data`:

```
int a;
int b = 1;
int c = 0;

$ size test.o
text      data    bss    dec     hex    filename
 91       4       4      99      5f test.o
```