# C: Uninitialized int type size bigger then must be

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Uninitialized `int` variable [will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#BSS) be placed to the `.bss` section.

But if I add such a variable - the `bss` section length in `size`'s results became bigger onto 8 bytes instead of 4 - why so?

Here is an example:

With one uninitialized integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
//int b;

int main () {

    printf("A size: %d\n", sizeof(a));
//    printf("B size: %d\n", sizeof(b));
    return 0;

}
```

The `size`'s result:

> ```
> $ gcc int_szie.c -o int_szie
> $ size int_szie
>    text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
>    1483     536       8    2027     7eb int_szie
> ```

Uncomment `b` var - and now `bss` is 16 bytes:

```
...
int a;
int b;

int main () {

    printf("A size: %d\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("B size: %d\n", sizeof(b));
    return 0;
...
```

> ```
> $ gcc int_szie.c -o int_szie
> $ size int_szie                                                                                                                                                     
>    text    data     bss     dec     hex filename                                                                                                                                                                                              
>    1628     592      16    2236     8bc int_szie
> ```

`sizeof()` results:

> ```
> $ ./int_szie                                                                                                                                                                     
> A size: 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
> B size: 4
> ```

And I'm even afraid to ask why the `data` section became bigger on whole 56 bytes:

> data 536

Vs:

> data 592

The `gcc`:

> ```
> $ gcc --version
> gcc (GCC) 7.1.1 20170630
> ```

Comment: To avoid distractions with using a mis-matched specifier/type - which is UB, use `printf("A size: %zu\n", sizeof(a));` or `printf("A size: %d\n", (int) sizeof(a));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the same code, just added `long long b`. The code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int a;
 long long b;

 int main () {

     printf("A size: %d\n", sizeof(a));
     //    printf("B size: %d\n", sizeof(b));
         return 0;

 }
```

The `objdump` output is following:

```
mdeore@mdeore-Lenovo:~$ objdump -t ./a.out

./a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000400238 l    d  .interp    0000000000000000              .interp
0000000000400254 l    d  .note.ABI-tag  0000000000000000              .note.ABI-tag
0000000000400274 l    d  .note.gnu.build-id 0000000000000000              .note.gnu.build-id
0000000000400298 l    d  .gnu.hash  0000000000000000              .gnu.hash
00000000004002b8 l    d  .dynsym    0000000000000000              .dynsym
0000000000400318 l    d  .dynstr    0000000000000000              .dynstr
0000000000400358 l    d  .gnu.version   0000000000000000              .gnu.version
0000000000400360 l    d  .gnu.version_r 0000000000000000              .gnu.version_r
0000000000400380 l    d  .rela.dyn  0000000000000000              .rela.dyn
0000000000400398 l    d  .rela.plt  0000000000000000              .rela.plt
00000000004003c8 l    d  .init  0000000000000000              .init
00000000004003f0 l    d  .plt   0000000000000000              .plt
0000000000400420 l    d  .plt.got   0000000000000000              .plt.got
0000000000400430 l    d  .text  0000000000000000              .text
00000000004005c4 l    d  .fini  0000000000000000              .fini
00000000004005d0 l    d  .rodata    0000000000000000              .rodata
00000000004005e0 l    d  .eh_frame_hdr  0000000000000000              .eh_frame_hdr
0000000000400618 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000              .eh_frame
0000000000600e10 l    d  .init_array    0000000000000000              .init_array
0000000000600e18 l    d  .fini_array    0000000000000000              .fini_array
0000000000600e20 l    d  .jcr   0000000000000000              .jcr
0000000000600e28 l    d  .dynamic   0000000000000000              .dynamic
0000000000600ff8 l    d  .got   0000000000000000              .got
0000000000601000 l    d  .got.plt   0000000000000000              .got.plt


0000000000601028 l    d  .data  0000000000000000              .data
0000000000601038 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000              .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000              .comment
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              crtstuff.c
0000000000600e20 l     O .jcr   0000000000000000              __JCR_LIST__
0000000000400460 l     F .text  0000000000000000              deregister_tm_clones
00000000004004a0 l     F .text  0000000000000000              register_tm_clones
00000000004004e0 l     F .text  0000000000000000              __do_global_dtors_aux


0000000000601038 l     O .bss   0000000000000001              completed.7585
0000000000600e18 l     O .fini_array    0000000000000000              __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000400500 l     F .text  0000000000000000              frame_dummy
0000000000600e10 l     O .init_array    0000000000000000              __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              abc.c
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              crtstuff.c
0000000000400708 l     O .eh_frame  0000000000000000              __FRAME_END__
0000000000600e20 l     O .jcr   0000000000000000              __JCR_END__
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000
0000000000600e18 l       .init_array    0000000000000000              __init_array_end
0000000000600e28 l     O .dynamic   0000000000000000              _DYNAMIC
0000000000600e10 l       .init_array    0000000000000000              __init_array_start
00000000004005e0 l       .eh_frame_hdr  0000000000000000              __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000601000 l     O .got.plt   0000000000000000              _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
00000000004005c0 g     F .text  0000000000000002              __libc_csu_fini
0000000000000000  w      *UND*  0000000000000000              _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
0000000000601028  w      .data  0000000000000000              data_start
0000000000601040 g     O .bss   0000000000000008              b       <<<<<<<< 'b' is 8 bytes
0000000000601038 g       .data  0000000000000000              _edata
00000000004005c4 g     F .fini  0000000000000000              _fini
0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000000              printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000000              __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000601028 g       .data  0000000000000000              __data_start
0000000000000000  w      *UND*  0000000000000000              __gmon_start__
0000000000601030 g     O .data  0000000000000000              .hidden __dso_handle
00000000004005d0 g     O .rodata    0000000000000004              _IO_stdin_used
0000000000400550 g     F .text  0000000000000065              __libc_csu_init
0000000000601050 g       .bss   0000000000000000              _end
0000000000400430 g     F .text  000000000000002a              _start
0000000000601048 g     O .bss   0000000000000004              a       <<<<<<<<< 'a' is 4 bytes
0000000000601038 g       .bss   0000000000000000              __bss_start
0000000000400526 g     F .text  000000000000001f              main
0000000000000000  w      *UND*  0000000000000000              _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000601038 g     O .data  0000000000000000              .hidden __TMC_END__
0000000000000000  w      *UND*  0000000000000000              _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000004003c8 g     F .init  0000000000000000              _init
```

The output shows correctly, the `int a` is 4 bytes and `long long b` is 8 bytes.

`size <objfile>` shows the size of `.bss` segment and not the size of a particular variable. To verify this fact, remove both `a` and `b` global variables from the code and now check size of `.bss` segment, you will still see the size as 8.

There is similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962014/why-bss-segment-is-16-by-default) where the size differs on Windows operating system.